# External Links in iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe

Is it possible to make links in an iframe open in a new window? And if so how would I go about doing this? I'm sure there's going to be more than one method so if you can post as many as possible. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The same way as if it wasn't in an iframe, with `target="_blank"`

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">Foo Bar</a>
```